# Force Debounce to Finish?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this debounce I setup on my handleChange method.  It works as expected, UNLESS we have a speed typist.  If you type in the field, then tab to the next field and keep typing, then it never finished updating the value of the first field.  Is there a way to makes sure that completes no matter how fast someone moves on? In the end my plan is to write the data to a database through an API call.  Things can get out of sync fast if I can't guarantee it'll always grab and send the data.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    const targetName = e.target.name;
    const targetValue = e.target.value;

    if (this.state.editingTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.state.editingTimeout);
    }

    this.setState({
      editing: false,
      editingTimeout: setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`${targetName}: ${targetValue}`);
        this.setState({
          [targetName]: targetValue,
        });
      }, 300),
    });
  };
```

Comment: Are you sure you are debouncing correctly? With debouncing when the "action" that causes a callback to be debounced stops and the debounce duration expires then the callback is invoked with the latest data. Looks like you are debouncing the state update, yes? Is the issue you've only a single global component debounce timer, so if a quick typist gets to the next field and continues typing faster than the debounce rate the last field isn't "completed"?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the problem.  I'm basically trying to auto save values typed into the fields as you go.  I do not want the lag in typing, also do not want the value getting resaved with every keystroke, because I also want to send to database after certain delay.  I just cannot figure out the right way.

Comment: Many react form managers can validate form fields on change, and also on blur. You may want to implement an `onBlur` callback for each field so that when the user tabs to the next field it can immediately trigger the last validation without delay. I am not sure if keeping the single "debounce" timer would still work here though so you may need to play with it. Have you considered any form management packages, like redux-form, formik, etc...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store a timeout for each different element using the handler

```js
// editingTimeout should be an object in the state
handleChange = (e) => {
  const targetName = e.target.name;
  const targetValue = e.target.value;

  this.setState(state => {
    clearTimeout(this.state.editingTimeout[targetName]);
    return ({
      editing: false,
      editingTimeout: {
        ...state.editingTimeout,
        [targetName]: setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(`${targetName}: ${targetValue}`);
          this.setState({
            [targetName]: targetValue,
          });
        }, 300),
      }
    })
  });
};
```

Comment: This appears to be what I needed, thanks!  However, there seems to be a lag when I type.  Do you think this could be the cause?

Comment: @AdamNorton Yes, it would have a delay, and your original code should have it too (*if the input is controlled*).